# cfoutput from a query created with cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm late to the party by trying to catch up on cfscript syntax.  I've created a simple query in cfscript that executes and dumps out the correct data just fine:

```
qPositive = new Query(datasource="#APPLICATION.DSN#");
qPositive.setSQL(" my sql here ");
qPositive.addParam(name="xid",value="178",CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INT");
qryPositive = qPositive.execute();  
writeDump(qryPositive.getResult());
```

Gives me exactly what I expect.  However, in the actual page

```
<cfoutput query="qryPositive">
```

throws an error that it's not defined.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? `new Query` has been replaced in newer versions with `QueryExecute()`

Comment: As you've said below, you have to use `getResult()` for the query results to actually exist. Since these are chainable, I usually just automatically chain `x.execute().getResult()`. I don't think `execute()` by itself will give you much info to work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `getResult()` after `execute()`

```
qryPositive = qPositive.execute().getResult();
```